# Order a list of Core Data entities alphabetically off one attribute - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsset

I have two entities in my project, DBTeam and DBPlayer. DBTeam has a one to many relationship with DBPlayer allowing multiple players to be associated with one team; DBPlayer then has an attribute called name which is what I want to base the alphabetical order off of. What's the easiest way to list these alphabetically off of name?

Here is the code I am using to list them at the moment. I have tried `.sorted` but that just produced other errors.

```
struct PlayersView: View{

    var team: DBTeam

    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(Array(team.player as? Set<DBPlayer> ?? []), id: \.id){ player in //I want to sort this ForEach here
                    Text(player.name ?? "Player Name")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Players")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`:

```
List {
    let array = Array(team.player as? Set<DBPlayer> ?? [])
        .sorted { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.name) == .orderedAscending }
    ForEach(array, id: \.id) { player in
        Text(player.name ?? "Player Name")
    }
}
```